# Simple Number Guessing Game. C++

Tags: c++, loops, random

I've been trying to make a simple game where the computer generates a random number and you try to guess it. It also stores the amount of guesses you make "tries".

However, when I run the program, it simply prints: "Let's play a game. I'll think of a number 1-100. Try to guess it."

Here's my code:

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main()

    {
        using namespace std;

        int the_number;
        int guess;
        int tries;

        the_number = rand() % 101 + 1;

        cout << "Let's play a game!";
        cout << "I will think of a number 1-100. Try to guess it.";
        cout << endl;
        cin >> guess;

        for (tries = 0; tries++;)
        {
            if (guess == the_number)
            {
                cout << "You guessed it!";
                cout << "And it only took you: " << tries;
            }
            else if (guess < the_number)
            {
                cout << "Higher";
                tries++;
            }


            else if (guess > the_number)
            {
                cout << "Lower";
                tries++;
            }

            else
                cout << "That's not even in range!";
            return 0;





    }



}
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work, could someone explain why not?

Comment: `for (tries = 0; tries++;)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `while` loop here, not `for`:

```
while (the_number != guess)
{
    //
    //
}
```

And try using the new `<random>` header instead of `rand()` function:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;

std::default_random_engine engine(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 100);

the_number = uniform_dist(engine);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your program does not print anything after "Let's play a game. I'll think of a number 1-100. Try to guess it." is the way you have written your `for` loop.

```
for ( tries = 0; tries++; )
```

breaks out of the loop without doing anything because `tries++` evaluates to `0`.

Also, for your program to work correctly, you need to add more code to read guesses. Something like the code below, should work.

```
   for (tries = 0; ; tries++)
   {
      if (guess == the_number)
      {
         cout << "You guessed it!";
         cout << "And it only took you " << tries << " tries.\n";
         break;
      }
      else if (guess < the_number)
      {
         cout << "Higher";
         cin >> guess;
      }

      else if (guess > the_number)
      {
         cout << "Lower";
         cin >> guess;
      }
   }
```

Comment: @R Sahu  Actually,  it seems to always generate the number 42 each time. Is there a way to have it generate a new number each time I run it?

Comment: @Gold, you needs to seed that random number generator. You can use `srand(time(NULL))` or use the suggestion by @w.b.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a couple of variables that will make your code more understandable, something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{char EndGame = 'N';
    int MyNumber = 150 , playerguess;
    cout << "I have a number between 1 and 100.\nCan you guess my number ??\nPlease type your first guess.\n?" << endl;

    do{
        cin >> playerguess;
    if (playerguess > MyNumber) {
        cout << " Too High. Try again." << endl;

    }

    else if (playerguess == MyNumber) {
        cout << "Excellent ! You Got It ! \n If you want to exit press Y" << endl;
        cin >> EndGame;
        break;

    }
    else {
        cout << " Too Low. Try again." << endl;
    }
    } while (1);
return 0;
}
```

This will make the number equal to **150**. Each time the user inputs a value, the console will determine whether it is higher, lower or equal to the number.

If you want instead to make it a random number each time, you can simply use the `<random>` library and use the module operator with a number like 100 or 101. Then, you can add 1; this will generate only positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is wrong (it needs 3 things: initialization, check condition and the todo step after each loop.
For example:

```
for (tries = 0; tries < 5; tries++)
```

Also you loop the guessing part, but you forget to ask the user for a new number. I would suggest to move the `cin << guess` into the for loop.